# using jquery to pull a table into an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi asked a similar question yesterday but here it goes.

Firstly: **All data is on my domain. all data is on the same domain. the loading iframe is on the same domain.** Thank you.

For reference.. the table name is dactable, and the div name is tablediv (if you wish to write something new and what tags i can understand).

Now heres the code im using to pull the table.

```
$(window).on('load', function() // wait for load event, so the iframe is fully loaded in
{
  var $iframe = $('iframe'); // assuming only one?  You need to target the right iframe, perahps with iframe[src="/top_list.html"] if that's your only option

  var $contents = $iframe.contents();
  var $main = $contents.find('.main');
  var $tbl = $main.next(); // now we have the table

  $contents.find('*').hide(); // hide everything
  $tbl.show(); // show table and...

  var $parent = $tbl.parent(); // get/show all parents of the tbl

  while($parent.length)
  {
     $parent.show(); // show parent
     $parent = $parent.parent(); // move up the hierarchy
  }
});
```

Now i also need to remove certain columns. but cant seem to get it working to do more then 1.

Also how does it know what table to target?

```
$('table tr').each(
    function(tr_idx,el){
        $(el).children('td').each(
            function(td_idx,el2){
                //i'm removing first columns..
                if(td_idx == 0){
                    el2.remove();
                }
        });//inner each
});//outer each
```

Thank you

Comment: You are not pulling a table into an iframe, you are modifying a table that lives in an iframe. Any reason why it is in an iframe and not just a div with overflow auto?

Comment: I have data on a page. i can not repeat this data or code on any otherpage. its impossible. restricted in the api i guess. so i can only load the whole page into an iframe when i need to use the data a strip away everything i dont need. is this possible in a div?

Comment: It is possible using ajax. You already have all the tools you need, since you are using jQuery

Comment: The table that i wish to pull has to much info so once i do pull it into an iframe i then need to remove columns

Comment: not good with the xml side in ajax

Comment: Ajax is something i do want to look into for further development but right now a straight jquery im sure is possibe.

Comment: i'll provide an example. it is VERY straightforward

Comment: thank you your gonna get me going on ajax early arent you more tools more options :)

Comment: Check my answer below. It's only 5 lines of code. There is really no need to fear ajax. the sooner you get into it, the sooner you will realize how easy it is to use (with jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.load()` to load the html you want into a div of your choice. You can even choose which part of the html to load by specifying providing an #id after the url

```
$(function () {

    $('#result').load('/top_list.html #table-id', function () {

        $('#result table tr').each() {
              //remove first td of each row
              $(this).children('td').first().remove();
        });

    });

});
```

It's that simple. It helps that everything is on the same domain too

---

To make this a bit more clear, let's assume you have the following table

```
<table id="table-id">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first cell of each row is removed and the result is placed in a div

```
<div id="result">
    <table id="table-id">
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: hey that looks beautiful, how do i remove specific colomns rather then just the first child.

Comment: You can use the `.filter()` function and the [:eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead of `.first()`. For example `$(this).children('td').filter(':eq(1)').remove()` will remove the 2nd column.

Comment: gone through it many times getting better at it ... the page dosent state how to remove multiple lines. can i do this$(this).children('td').filter(':eq(1,2,4)').remove()

Comment: `.filter(':eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(4)')` but this is starting to look messy. You could always add an extra class to the cells you are removing and just filter them using the class instead of their index

Comment: i give you a beautiful 5 line solution and you go with the ugly, inefficient one? I feel sorry for wasting my time here...

Comment: lol no chance of course i went with yours, LIKE YOU SAID "BEAUTIFUL". BUT I DO LIKE TO CREDIT OTHER PEOPLE WHO GIVE THERE TIME ;#) sry ticked the wrong one. i can not edit the source table as it grabs xml data and is restricted in the api blah blah blah so will do the messy eq(1), ETC. THANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to remove rows and columns by indexes.

```
var removeRows(table, rows){
    // mark a row, which should be removed
    $('tr', table).each(function(tr_idx){
        if(rows.indexOf(tr_idx) !== -1){
            // rows contains tr_idx
            $(this).attr("remove");
        }
    });
    // remove marked rows
    $('tr[remove]', table).remove();
},
removeColumns(table, columns){
    // mark a column, which should be removed
    $('tr', table).each(function(tr_idx){
        $('td', this).each(function(td_idx){
            if(columns.indexOf(td_idx) !== -1){
                // columns contains td_idx
                $(this).attr("remove");
            }
        };
    });
    // remove marked columns
    $('td[remove]', table).remove();
};

...
var table = $(something);

// remove rows with indexes 1, 2 and 3
removeRows(table, [1, 2, 3]); 

// remove columns with indexes 0 and 3
removeColumns(table, [0, 3]);
```

Comment: is the "-1" as to not give it a index to remove and uses the bottom list to remove the indexes?

Comment: The indexOf() method returns -1 if the item is not found. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

The expression (rows.indexOf(tr_idx) === -1) means, that there are no rows with the index tr_idx in the "rows" array.